# Jersey 2 (JAXB) XML element case with list not honoring XmlRootElement

Tags: xml, jaxb, jersey, jersey-2.0

We just upgraded a service from Jersey 1.x to 2.10.x and are seeing some unexpected behavior.  We have a class like this that is annotated to marshal as 'User' instead of 'user':

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "User", namespace = "security.services.pml.com")
public class User {
    @XmlElement(namespace = "security.services.pml.com", required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(namespace = "security.services.pml.com", required = true)
    protected String nickname;
}
```

When we have a resource method that returns a List of User we get XML with the following format (note the lowercase "users" parent element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<users>
    <User xmlns="security.services.pml.com">
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <nickname>Jackie</nickname>
    </User>
</users>
```

We expect Jersey to instead pluralize **User** (from the annotation) to come up with **Users** instead of **users**.

In Jersey 1.x we dealt with this Jersey bug by putting the following config property into our web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.XmlRootElementProcessing</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

But that seems to have no effect in Jersey 2.x, and we can't find a new property to give the same result.  We obviously could instead return a properly annotated object called Users that contained a list of User and get the desired result, but we didn't have to do that with Jersey 1.x.

Does anybody know what we are missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the servlet definition, in web.xml the new property name is:

```
 <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.jaxb.collections.processXmlRootElement</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

If setting it in code, it would be:

```
       .property("jersey.config.jaxb.collections.processXmlRootElement", true);
```

See: [Jersey 2 Constants](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/constant-values.html)
Which links to the [MessageProperties constant JAXB_PROCESS_XML_ROOT_ELEMENT](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/message/MessageProperties.html#JAXB_PROCESS_XML_ROOT_ELEMENT)

This fixes the issue in Jersey 2.x that was addressed by com.sun.jersey.config.feature.XmlRootElementProcessing in Jersey 1.x.

It is [documented here](http://www.javadocs.com/docs/org.glassfish.jersey/jax-rs-ri/2.0-m12/org/glassfish/jersey/message/MessageProperties.html).